# Iterate through nested dict items

Tags: html, python-3.x

```
dict_items([('props', {'children': [{'props': {'children': 'Results'}, 'type': 'H4', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}, {'props': {'children': {'props': {'children': [{'props': {'children': 'advsot_20181104.xlsx'}, 'type': 'Td', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}], 'href': 'http:group.net/advsot_output/advsot_20181104.xlsx'}, 'type': 'A', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}}, 'type': 'Tr', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}]}), ('type', 'Table'), ('namespace', 'dash_html_components')])
```

I have a function that returns this dictionary but I want to loop through it and retrieve the href link but nothing I have tried works so far. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is not a dictionary — it is a view on the items of that dictionary (probably gotten through `my_dict.items()`).

In your case, it appears that you could access the link through `my_dict["props"]["children"][1]["props"]["children"]["props"]["href"]`, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it if you tell us where your dictionary comes from exactly.

---

If there's no other way, you could do it using a recursive function:

```
def find_value(d, key="href"):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key in d:
            if key == "href":
                return d[key]
            result = find_value(d[key], key)
            if result:
                return result
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for element in d:
            result = find_value(element, key)
            if result:
                return result
```

Then you can call it with your dictionary:

```
>>> find_value(my_dict)
'http:group.net/advsot_output/advsot_20181104.xlsx'
```

---

If there can be several occurrences of the key, and you want to be able to find all, use this generator alternative:

```
def find_values(d, key="href"):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key in d:
            if key == "href":
                yield d[key]
            yield from find_values(d[key], key)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for element in d:
            yield from find_values(element, key)
```

You use it by iterating over it:

```
>>> for url in find_values(my_dict, "href"):
...     print(url)
group.net/advsot_output/advsot_20181104.xlsx
```

If you just want a list, call `list()` on it:

```
>>> list(find_values(my_dict, "href"))
['group.net/advsot_output/advsot_20181104.xlsx', ...]
```

Comment: {'props': {'children': [{'props': {'children': 'Results'}, 'type': 'H4', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}, {'props': {'children': {'props': {'children': [{'props': {'children': 'advsot_20181104.xlsx'}, 'type': 'Td', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}], 'href': 'http://group.net/advsot_output/advsot_20181104.xlsx'}, 'type': 'A', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}}, 'type': 'Tr', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'}]}, 'type': 'Table', 'namespace': 'dash_html_components'} - This is my dict which comes from a html table created from a dataframe

Comment: If you have no way to influence that, my second solution may be of help; it can find the (first occurrence of the) `href` key.

Comment: Thank you, your second solution is what I need. But for what I am doing I am going to have multiple items. Therefore, I could have more than one href link. So how do I modify your solution to find all occurrences

Comment: @Dan I edited my answer to include a solution for multiple items.